# Disable scroll on sencha dataview list

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2.3

In sencha touch 2.3.1 there is no property named scrollable on the Ext.dataview.List. How can I disable scrolling on a Ext.dataview.List ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the scrollable Property on parent element:

http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/#!/api/Ext.Panel-cfg-scrollable